Enable eslint autofix into Intelij from .editorconfig?
Is it possible to enable eslint autofix in Intellij from .editorconfig instead of manual configuration?
Manual Config Intellij:

I am looking for something like this:
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}]
ij_eslint_enable = true
ij_eslint_auto_fix_on_save = true

Is there any other way to configure run on save operations?

Found a way by sharing in Git
.idea/jsLinters/eslint.xml file which configure the behaviour of eslint module.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="EslintConfiguration">
    <files-pattern value="**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,cjs,cts,mjs,mts,html,json}" />
    <option name="fix-on-save" value="true" />
  </component>
</project>

